# Kafka Connect Hangs when Kafka Node Goes Down

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

we are testing out kafka connect and in our testing noticed that when one of our kafka nodes goes down or is unavailable, kafka connect goes down (hangs).

In our rest and distributed properties, our broker configuration looks like: dp-kafka-01:9092, dp-kafka-02:9092, dp-kafka-03:9092.

We are looking at possibly using a load balancer to maintain uptime but I would be interested in seeing 1) if others have had this problem 2) their solution to it.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a load balancer in front of the Connect REST API will not stop them from crashing upon broker failure.

You need to administer Kafka better to prevent the whole system from going down.